# Почему при скролле срабатывает функция в ngFor

Tags: angular2

Объясните пожалуйста, почему при скролле каждый раз срабатывает функция filterPhones()
Вот пример кода:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', host: {
        '(window:scroll)': 'onScroll($event)'
    },
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <div *ngFor="let phone of filterPhones()">
  {{phone}}
  </div>`
})

export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
public phones=[123,456,7689];
constructor(){
    for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
    this.phones.push(i)
  }
}
 onScroll($event) {return}

  filterPhones(){
    console.log(1)
    return this.phones
  }
}
```

[вот пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/p4k0U6twQxOitN6z6QnJ?p=preview)

Comment: а если убрать подписку на scroll?

Comment: @Grundy Если убрать подписку, то функция отрабатывает один раз и все работает так как и ожидалось. Но в моем приложении я не могу убрать подписку на скролл(есть функционал на нем завязанный). Для меня важно не решить эту проблему, а понять почему так происходит и как это работает.

Comment: из-за этой подписки и происходит

Comment: Так а как связана подписка на скролл с этой функцией, если явно нигде не указано, что при скролле необходимо вызвать эту функцию? Почему каждый раз происходит перерисовка DOM ?

Comment: скорее всего просто в таком случае запускается _change detection_ и ангуляру нужно проверить что ничего не изменилось